# SOIL Load PNG Image into a Texture turns into an grey image

Tags: c++, image, opengl, glfw, soil

So I want to load a PNG image using SOIL, like this:

```
unsigned char* image = SOIL_load_image("image.png", &width, &height, 0, SOIL_LOAD_AUTO);

glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGB, width, height, 0, GL_RGB, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
glGenerateMipmap(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
SOIL_free_image_data(image);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
```

When I use a JPEG image everything is loaded and rendered as I expect... but when I try to load a PNG image, I get the following result:

[image: rendered image in PNG format]

Any one knows what could be wrong in here?!

Comment: This looks like the Image is actually in RGBA? Just a random guess

Comment: Hi WorldSEnder... I've tried too..it's not that:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WorldSEnder was right :) It was indeed a RBGA image.

I missed the:

```
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, width, height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image);
```

Thanks!